# Swift: Argument labels naming convention?

Tags: swift, user-interface, naming-conventions, naming

Suppose I want to hide/show an UI element using one function. What is the correct way to name it?

```
func changeRefreshControlVisibilityTo(_ isVisible: Bool) {}
```

or

```
func changeRefreshControlVisibility(to isVisible: Bool) {}
```

Do people have thoughts and/or references for this? Thanks!

Comment: This https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#parameter-names probably is a good reference.

Answer (score 1):

I personally wouldn't go with neither of these. The `change` part seems redundant to me, especially taking into account the fact, that it might not really change anything - let's say, that current visibility is `false` and you still can set `false` as the argument of this method.

So if you want to stick to word `change`, maybe something like that:

```
func changeRefreshControlVisibility() {}
```

or to me, even better one:

```
func toggleRefreshControlVisibility() {}
```

would be sufficient?

And if you want to openly communicate what value will the visibility have after using this method, why not simply:

```
func setRefreshControlVisible(_ isVisible: Bool) {}
```

Anyway, the API design guidelines for Swift are rather brief:

https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/

So my general impression is that you should go with whatever suits you/your team best.